# How can i explode the string with , and |

Tags: php, explode

How can i explode this? `mars@email.com,123,12,1|art@hur.com,321,32,2`

the output should be :

```
$email = mars@email.com
$score = 123
$street = 12
$rank = 1
```

then remove the `|`

```
$email = art@hur.com
$score = 321
$street = 32
$rank = 2


$string = mars@email.com,123,12,1|art@hur.com,321,32,2
explode( ',', $string );
```

is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach(explode('|', $str) as $v){
     $data = explode(',',$v);
     echo '$email = '.$data[0].
     '$score = '.$data[1].
     '$street = '.$data[2].
     '$rank = '.$data[3];
 }
```

Comment: For a known/unchanging/small number of data pieces, it would be cleaner and less error-prone to use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) (e.g. `list($email, $score, $street, $rank) = explode(',', $v);`)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use strtok() rather than explode().

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = preg_split( '"[,|]"', 'mars@email.com,123,12,1|art@hur.com,321,32,2' );
$len = count($arr);
for( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i+=4 ) {
    $email = $arr[$i];
    $score = $arr[$i+1];
    $street = $arr[$i+2];
    $rank = $arr[$i+3];
}
```

Comment: how can i print this without the array?

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the new array in variable >

```
$arr = explode(',',$string);
```

and I dont get what you want to do with the second part (after the `|`), but you can get the first par by doing this > `$half = explode('|',$string)[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to unravel it in the right order:

- first the blocks separated by `|`
- then individual cells separated by `,`

A concise way to do so is:

```
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("|", $data));
```

Will give you a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok and explode.

```
$tok = strtok($string, "|");

while ($tok !== false) {
    list($email, $score, $street, $rank) = explode(',', $tok);
    $tok = strtok(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this

```
   $output = array();

foreach (explode('|', $string) as $person) {
    $output[] = array(
        'email'   =>    $person[0],
        'score'   =>    $person[1],
        'street'  =>    $person[2],
        'rank'    =>    $person[3]
    )
}
```

This stores all the results in a multidimensional array. For example, to print person 1's email, you'd use

```
echo $output[0]['email'];   // mars@email.com
```

and to access person 2's street, you'd use

```
echo $output[1]['street'];   // 32
```